# Multiple tabs in PuTTY

Tags: putty, terminal-emulator

I connect to RHEL 7 via Putty. I want to have multitab functionality inside. But when I press "Ctrl-Shift-T" nothing happen.

How can I have multitab functionality?

Comment: Do you mean having multiple screens in your putty session? There are a few ways I know of for doing this, if that is the case.

Comment: i want to have several tabs so I can open several folders / run several programs

Comment: I use screen and tmux for this. I actually have a script in tmux that implements this. I will add an answer for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you connect via Putty, that is not the same as opening a terminal program on the desktop (there you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).

You'll have to install an X server on your Windows machine (like MingW) and then you can use any X client including such a terminal program that support multiple tabs.

Alternatively use `tmux` or `screen` to start an application with multiple windows. They are simpler to install (if not already available) and have the advantage that they stay "alive" even if your Putty based connection goes down. I.e. you can log back in and reconnect to the `tmux`/`screen` session and carry on working in all the windows you had opened.

Comment: in `tmux` can I place all tabs "side by side", so I can view them all at once?

Comment: @javapowered You can split the window in panes, they will of course become small

Answer (score 1):

You can use tmux to have multiple screens/windows running. Below is a snippet of a script that i Use to show you an example of this:

```
#Declares winod WinSplit
tmux new-window -a -n WinSplit
tmux new-session -d -s WinSplit -n SSH0 -d
tmux selectp -t WinSplit

#Binds Keys, activates window activity, color coding of panes
tmux bind-key -n M-Left previous-window -t WinSplit
tmux bind-key -n M-Right next-window -t WinSplit
tmux set-window-option -g monitor-activity on
tmux set -g visual-activity on
tmux set-window-option -g window-status-current-bg blue
tmux set-window-option -g window-status-fg red
tmux set -g pane-border-fg yellow
tmux set -g pane-active-border-bg red
tmux set -g message-fg yellow
tmux set -g message-bg red
tmux set -g message-attr bright
tmux set -g status-left "#[fg=red]#S"

#names the panes/windows that are split
tmux new-window -n SSH1 -t WinSplit
tmux new-window -n SSH2 -t WinSplit
tmux new-window -n SFTP -t WinSplit
tmux new-window -n portalDB -t WinSplit
tmux new-window -n JoinCode -t WinSplit
tmux new-window -n Profile -t WinSplit
tmux new-window -n Username -t WinSplit
tmux new-window -n bash0 -t WinSplit
tmux new-window -n bash1 -t WinSplit
tmux new-window -n bash2 -t WinSplit

#Calls script when windows are made and attached 
tmux send-keys -t WinSplit:0 './sshScript.sh' C-m
tmux send-keys -t WinSplit:1 './sshScript.sh' C-m
tmux send-keys -t WinSplit:2 './sshScript.sh' C-m
tmux send-keys -t WinSplit:3 './ftpConnect.sh' C-m
tmux send-keys -t WinSplit:4 'opendb' C-m
tmux send-keys -t WinSplit:5 './promptforJoinCode.sh' C-m
tmux send-keys -t WinSplit:6 './promptforProfile.sh' C-m
tmux send-key -t WinSplit:7 './promptforUsername.sh' C-m
tmux attach -t WinSplit
```

Answer (score 1):

I certainly agree with the other suggestions to use tmux/screen - this is "right way" to accomplish this task.

With that said, if the poster wants something incredibly simple, and isn't concerned with having the sessions restored if his/her Windows box disconnects, [MTPuTTY](http://ttyplus.com/multi-tabbed-putty/) would probably be the very easiest solution from a Windows client.